# Palindrome check with recursion in Lisp

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp, palindrome

I have developed code to check through input to see if it is a palindrome or not but I am having difficulty figuring out how to print the output. I want the output to return "t" if the input is a palindrome and "nil" if not. Also a challenge that I wanted to give myself was to not use the reverse function so thats why my code is not as simple as it could be. Thanks in advance.

```
(defun palindromep(l)
  (cond ((null l) nil (write nil))
        (t (append (list (car l)) (palindromep (cdr l)) (list (car l) )))))


        (palindromep '(a b b a))
        (terpri)
        (palindromep '(a b c b a))
        (terpri)
        (palindromep '(a b c))
        (terpri)
        (palindromep '(a (d e) (d e) a))
        (terpri)
        (palindromep '(a (d e) (e d) a))
```

Comment: Nowhere in your code is there any comparison: are two list elements the same or not. Therefore, it cannot be a palindrome checker.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, an empty list is a palindrome! If we reverse it, we get the same empty list.

Secondly, Lisp functions don't print their result values; they return these values.

In an interactive session, it is the listener which prints the resulting value(s) that emerge from the expression being evaluated. That expression itself doesn't have to print anything.

Therefore, we begin like this:

```
(defun palindromep (l)
  (cond
    ((null l) t) ;; the empty list is a palindrome: yield true.
```

Note, by the way, that if we write this:

```
    ((null l) nil t) ;; the empty list is a palindrome: yield true.
```

that doesn't do anything. The extra `nil` expression is evaluated, producing `nil`, which is thrown away. The Lisp compiler will completely eliminate that.

What if the list is not a list at all, but an atom other than `nil`? Let's just go with that being a palindrome. A clarification of requirements is needed, though:

```
    ((atom l) t)
```

Now we know we are dealing with a non-empty list. If it has exactly one item, then it is a palindrome:

```
    ((null (cdr l)) t)
```

Now we know we are dealing with a list of two or more items. That is a palindrome if the first and last items are the same, and if the items in between them form a palindrome.

```
    (t (let* ((first (car l))
              (rest (cdr l))
              (tail (last l))
              (interior (ldiff rest tail)))
         (and (eql first (car tail)) (palindromep interior))))))
```

The whole thing:

```
(defun palindromep (l)
  (cond
    ((null l) t)
    ((atom l) t)
    ((null (cdr l)) t)
    (t (let* ((first (car l))
              (rest (cdr l))
              (tail (last l))
              (interior (ldiff rest tail)))
         (and (eql first (car tail)) (palindromep interior))))))
```

Code golfing: in the `cond` construct described by ANSI CL, a clause is permitted to have just one form. If that forms yields a true value, then that value is returned. Thus we can remove the `t`'s:

```
(defun palindromep (l)
  (cond
    ((null l))        ;; t removed
    ((atom l))        ;; likewise
    ((null (cdr l)))  ;; likewise
    (t (let* ((first (car l))
              (rest (cdr l))
              (tail (last l))
              (interior (ldiff rest tail)))
         (and (eql first (car tail)) (palindromep interior))))))
```

Documentation about the functions `ldiff` and `last` can be [found here](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/c_conses.htm).

Further golfing: if we have this pattern `(cond (A) (B) ... (t Z))` we can just replace it by `(or A B ... Z)`:

```
(defun palindromep (l)
  (or (null l)
      (atom l)
      (let* ((first (car l))
             (rest (cdr l))
             (tail (last l))
             (interior (ldiff rest tail)))
        (and (eql first (car tail)) (palindromep interior)))))
```

`cond` is like a generalization of `or` that can specify an alternative result value for the each terminating true case.

Answer (score 0):

To go on with code-golfing, since `t` or `nil` is expected, you can use only `or` and `nil` to express conditionals (and using short-circuitry of `or` and `nil` expressions).

Also it is good to be able to determine a `:test` keyword - since you want to control the crucial testing behavior.
To be able to use also inner lists, one could e.g. use `equalp` or even a custom comparison function.

```
(defun palindromep (l &key (test #'equalp))
  (or (null l) (and (funcall test (car l) (car (last l)))
                    (palindromep (butlast (cdr l)) :test test))))
```

This evaluates

```
(palindromep '(a (d e) (d e) a))
```

as `t` but

```
(palindromep '(a (d e) (e d) a))
```

as `nil`.
Well, it is maybe a philosophical question, whether the latter should be `t` and the former `nil`.

To revert that behavior, we could write a custom testing function.

Like this:

```
(defun reverse* (l &optional (acc '()))
  (cond ((null l) acc)
        ((atom (car l)) (reverse* (cdr l) (cons (car l) acc)))
        (t (reverse* (cdr l) (cons (reverse* (car l) '()) acc)))))

(defun to-each-other-symmetric-p (a b)
  (cond ((and (atom a) (atom b)) (equalp a b))
        (t (equalp a (reverse* b)))))
```

Well, I use here some kind of a `reverse*`.

Then if one does:

```
(palindromep '(a (d e) (d e) a) :test #'to-each-other-symmetric-p) ;; NIL
;; and
(palindromep '(a (d e) (e d) a) :test #'to-each-other-symmetric-p) ;; T
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the other answers, I would like to point out that not using `reverse` will not only complicate your code enormously, but also make it far more inefficient. Just compare the above answers with the classic one:

```
(defun palindromep (l)
  (equal l (reverse l)))
```

`reverse` is o(l), i.e. it takes time proportional to the length of the list l, and so does `equal`. So this function will run in o(l). You can't get faster than this.

Comment: sure, but we avoided `reverse` because it was required. Secondly, in his listed tests probably he wants recursive testing in the sublists ...